# Using Video Recordings in Vuforia ARCamera

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, vuforia

I am trying to test Vuforia on some pre-recorded videos in a Unity project. However, I found that I can only use videos recorded by the Vuforia SessionRecorder. When I use video recorded by other apps or devices, even though its resolution, frame rate and encoding type are all the same as the Vuforia's sample recordings, I still get the following error,

```
Failed to start Vuforia
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.UnityLogger:LogError (string)
Vuforia.Internal.Utility.Log:Error (string)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:Start (System.Action)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:Start ()
Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour:VuforiaInitialized (Vuforia.VuforiaInitError)
System.Delegate:DynamicInvoke (object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeDelegate (System.Delegate,object[])
Vuforia.Utility.ExtensionMethods.DelegateHelper:InvokeWithExceptionHandling<Vuforia.VuforiaInitError> (System.Action`1<Vuforia.VuforiaInitError>,Vuforia.VuforiaInitError)
Vuforia.Internal.Core.Engine:add_OnAfterVuforiaInitializedPublic (System.Action`1<Vuforia.VuforiaInitError>)
Vuforia.VuforiaBehaviour:Awake ()
```

In addition to make sure the resolution, frame rate and encoding type the same, I used ffmpeg to check the metadata of Vuforia SessionRecorder's recordings and my own recordings, but I have no idea which property makes the difference. Below are the metadata of the two videos,

- Vuforia SessionRecorder's recording

```
ffprobe version 2023-06-27-git-9b6d191a66-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 13.101 / 58. 13.101
  libavcodec     60. 21.100 / 60. 21.100
  libavformat    60.  9.100 / 60.  9.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  8.102 /  9.  8.102
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\VuforiaSession-20230701-110737.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2023-07-01T16:07:37.000000Z
    title           : VuforiaSession-20230701-110737
    encoder         : Vuforia Engine
  Duration: 00:00:03.81, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15467 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Data: none (mp4s / 0x7334706D), 28 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-07-01T16:07:37.000000Z
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15428 kb/s, 29.94 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2023-07-01T16:07:37.000000Z
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 0
```

- My own recording

```
ffprobe version 2023-06-27-git-9b6d191a66-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
  libavutil      58. 13.101 / 58. 13.101
  libavcodec     60. 21.100 / 60. 21.100
  libavformat    60.  9.100 / 60.  9.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.100 / 60.  2.100
  libavfilter     9.  8.102 /  9.  8.102
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : clideo.com
    encoder         : Lavf60.9.100
  Duration: 00:00:02.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4898 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 269 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/bt470bg/smpte170m, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4620 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Anyone with any ideas about how to use non-Vuforia-recorded video will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The session recorder feature does not record only video but also other data coming for example from the device tracker (see here https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/recording-and-playback). Your files are surely missing these other data streams.

If you want to play back third party files one way is to write your own Vuforia File driver(https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/building-and-using-file-driver-sample)